# Manipulating a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to manipulate the result of a multi level category tree that dynamically gives me an array of objects that looks like this:

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 9
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 8
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 6
                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 7
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    ))
```

It basically tell us the id of the object and if it has any children. Pretty much like the menu builder in Wordpress.

What I'm trying to do is to transform this array into a new 2 level array, that would look like this:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 5
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 7
    ))
```

Where the first key ([0]) of the first level will be the ids that doesn't have any parents. So ids 1, 9 and 4 it's the main categories. And the sub sequential ones will be those that are parents. So, id 1 has 2 and 3 as children, id 4 has 8 and 5 as children, and so on.

I'm having a hard time to figure this out.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to work with this data as a plain array instead of objects? Where do you get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flattening a tree structure like this can be achieved using a recursive function. Here's an example that will work on your tree.

```
function flatten($array_of_objects, $key = 0, &$result = []) {

    // iterate the objects in the array
    foreach ($array_of_objects as $object) {

        // add each object's id to the result
        $result[$key][] = $object->id;

        // if the object has children, make the recursive call on that array
        if (isset($object->children)) {
            flatten($object->children, $object->id, $result);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wp_get_menu_array($current_menu) {

    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($current_menu);
    $menu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m1) {
        if (empty($m1->menu_item_parent)) {
            $menu[$m1->ID] = array();
            $menu[$m1->ID]['ID']             =   $m1->ID;
            $menu[$m1->ID]['title']          =   $m1->title;
            $menu[$m1->ID]['url']            =   $m1->url;
            $menu[$m1->ID]['children']       =   array();
            $childMenu = array();
            foreach ($array_menu as $m2) {
                if ($m2->menu_item_parent == $m1->ID) {
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID] = array();
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID]['ID']          =   $m2->ID;
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID]['title']       =   $m2->title;
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID]['url']         =   $m2->url;
                    $childMenu[$m2->ID]['children']       =   array();
                    $grandChildMenu = array();
                    foreach ($array_menu as $m3) {
                        if ($m3->menu_item_parent == $m2->ID) {
                            $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID] = array();
                            $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID]['ID']          =   $m3->ID;
                            $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID]['title']       =   $m3->title;
                            $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID]['url']         =   $m3->url;
                            $childMenu[$m3->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m3->ID] = $grandChildMenu[$m3->ID];
                        }
                    }
                    $menu[$m2->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m2->ID] = $childMenu[$m2->ID];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation along with the code would help anyone looking at your answer. Like a small summary of how you solved the problem.